# How can I avoid nested for loop in the below code?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, loop, for

Can anyone help on avoiding nested for loop in the below code:

```
 List<Account> leadAccountIds=[Select Id, OwnerId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :Liktr];
    System.debug('leadAccountIds=' + leadAccountIds);

    Map<String, Id> acctNameId=new Map<String, Id>();
    Map<String, Id> acctNameOwner=new Map<String, Id>();
    if(leadAccountIds.size()==1){
          For (Account a :leadAccountIds){

                  acctNameId.put(a.name,a.Id);
                  acctNameOwner.put(a.name,a.ownerId);
                  system.debug(acctNameOwner);
                  system.debug(acctNameId);

                For (Lead l2:trigger.new){
                         l2.ownerId=a.ownerId;
                         system.debug(a.ownerId);
                 }
           }
```

Thanks in advance!...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to set owners of the lead to the account you have queried. This can be done as follows.

```
List<Account> leadAccountIds=new List<Account>([Select Id, OwnerId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :Liktr]);

for(Account a :leadAccountIds) {
    //do any additional your if required
}
if(leadAccountIds.size() > 0) {
    for(Lead l2 : trigger.new) {
        l2.OwnerId = leadAccountIds[0].OwnerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
/* l2.ownerId=leadAccountIds.get(l2.PartnerAccountId).ownerId; */
If i Use that i can't assisgn account owner to lead right

Comment: Yes there was an issue. I've updated the answer

Comment: Hi @Ranga,
I don't Understand your answer, can you please